# How to add custom CSS in bottom of the page

Tags: 8, theming

Is there any function/way to add/include module custom CSS in the bottom of the page or after the closing body tag or in the footer? It is an auto-generated css and I can not add this css into library folder.

Right now I have included in *_module.html.twig* file, Below is the code which I used,

```
 $build['#cssFile'] = '/' . $cssPath;  

<style media="all">
 @import url("{{cssFile}}");
</style>
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure you can’t do this in a module. We recently tried to do something very similar, inject some CSS at the bottom of the head, and after many hours and many people’s time, we came to the conclusion it could only be done in html.html.twig at the theme level.

Comment: @Clive did you try this approach http://cgit.drupalcode.org/google_analytics/tree/google_analytics.module#n64 ?

Comment: @hugronaphor yep - unfortunately Drupal places the html head _above_ the css/js placeholders in all of its templates, so you can’t put something at the bottom of the head without providing a new template. Similar story for the end of the page

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Clive Just wanted to know one more thing here How to load CSS Asynchronously instead of importing? For eg. like this,  <link src="{{cssFile}}" media="unknown" /> Is that works?

Comment: HTML5 lets you do that, sure, but it’s not a brilliant idea. It causes inconsistencies in the way browsers render pages, and often ends up with a delay to styles being applied on load. For best results, have everything in a link in the head. If you feel like you’re being forced into placing it in the body for whatever reason, maybe re-examine the motivation and see if you can find an approach that lets you stick to best practice